# json parser error unexpected token

Tags: ruby, json

I am getting a json response array as below.

```
"[{\"id\":\"23886\",\"item_type\":2,\"name\":\"Equalizer\",\"label\":null,\"desc\":null,\"genre\":null,\"show_name\":null,\"img\":\"http:\\/\\/httpg3.scdn.arkena.com\\/10242\\/v2_images\\/tf1\\/0\\/tf1_media_ingest95290_image\\/tf1_media_ingest95290_image_0_208x277.jpg\",\"url\":\"\\/films\\/media-23886-Equalizer.html\",\"duration\":\"2h27mn\",\"durationtime\":\"8865\",\"audio_languages\":null,\"prod\":null,\"year\":null,\"vf\":\"1\",\"vost\":\"1\",\"sd\":true,\"hd\":false,\"sdprice\":\"4.99\",\"hdprice\":null,\"sdfile\":null,\"hdfile\":null,\"sdbundle\":\"12771\",\"hdbundle\":\"12771\",\"teaser\":\"23887\",\"att_getter\":\"Tout le monde a le droit \\u00e0 la justice\",\"orig_prod\":null,\"director\":null,\"actors\":null,\"csa\":\"CSA_6\",\"season\":null,\"episode\":null,\"typeid\":\"1\",\"isfav\":false,\"viewersrating\":\"4.0\",\"criticsrating\":\"3.0\",\"onThisPf\":1},{\"id\":\"23998\",\"item_type\":2,\"name\":\"Le Labyrinthe\",\"label\":null,\"desc\":null,\"genre\":null,\"show_name\":null,\"img\":\"http:\\/\\/httpg3.scdn.arkena.com\\/10242\\/v2_images\\/tf1\\/1\\/tf1_media_ingest94727_image\\/tf1_media_ingest94727_image_1_208x277.jpg\",\"url\":\"\\/films\\/media-23998-Le_Labyrinthe.html\",\"duration\":\"1h48mn\",\"durationtime\":\"6533\",\"audio_languages\":null,\"prod\":null,\"year\":null,\"vf\":\"1\",\"vost\":\"1\",\"sd\":true,\"hd\":false,\"sdprice\":\"4.99\",\"hdprice\":null,\"sdfile\":null,\"hdfile\":null,\"sdbundle\":\"12699\",\"hdbundle\":\"12699\",\"teaser\":\"23999\",\"att_getter\":\"Saurez-vous r\\u00e9chapper du labyrinthe ?\",\"orig_prod\":null,\"director\":null,\"actors\":null,\"csa\":\"CSA_1\",\"season\":null,\"episode\":null,\"typeid\":\"1\",\"isfav\":false,\"viewersrating\":\"3.5\",\"criticsrating\":\"4.0\",\"onThisPf\":1},{\"id\":\"23688\",\"item_type\":2,\"name\":\"Gone Girl\",\"label\":null,\"desc\":null,\"genre\":null,\"show_name\":null,\"img\":\"http:\\/\\/httpg3.scdn.arkena.com\\/10242\\/v2_images\\/tf1\\/0\\/tf1_media_ingest92895_image\\/tf1_media_ingest92895_image_0_208x277.jpg\",\"url\":\"\\/films\\/media-23688-Gone_Girl.html\",\"duration\":\"2h22mn\",\"durationtime\":\"8579\",\"audio_languages\":null,\"prod\":null,\"year\":null,\"vf\":\"1\",\"vost\":\"1\",\"sd\":true,\"hd\":false,\"sdprice\":\"4.99\",\"hdprice\":null,\"sdfile\":null,\"hdfile\":null,\"sdbundle\":\"12507\",\"hdbundle\":\"12507\",\"teaser\":\"23689\",\"att_getter\":\"Il ne faut pas se fier aux apparences...\",\"orig_prod\":null,\"director\":null,\"actors\":null,\"csa\":\"CSA_2\",\"season\":null,\"episode\":null,\"typeid\":\"1\",\"isfav\":false,\"viewersrating\":\"4.0\",\"criticsrating\":\"4.5\",\"onThisPf\":1}]"
```

While I try to parse it, I get Unexpected token Parser Error, which I believe is due to the quotes at the beginning and end of the response.

I was wrong to say that the parser error was due to the quotes at the beginning and end of response. But I am not sure why it happens. But when I try to parse the json response array, it does throw error.
Any idea whether there is anything wrong in the json respnse array.

Comment: What is "ruby script array"?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It is parsed successfully as is.

Comment: How did you try to parse it ?

Comment: Ruby will parse this as-is: http://ideone.com/TbnzoA

Comment: @Johnsyweb I tried to parse it but it throws parser error. I tried as below JSON.parse(File.read('demo')). The demo file contains the json response which I pasted.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to parse it but it throws parser error. I tried as below
>   JSON.parse(File.read('demo')). The demo file contains the json
>   response which I pasted.

First of all, the json you posted is a ruby String.  And ruby parses it as json without error.  However, if you paste that string into a file, it will not be valid json because of the *escape sequences*, the most numerous of which is `\"`.

In a ruby string, the sequence `\"`, which is two characters long, is converted to one character; in a file that same sequence is two characters long: a `\` and a `"`.  In other words, escape sequences that are legal inside a ruby String do not represent the same thing when pasted into a file.

Another example: in a ruby String the escape sequence `\20AC` is a single character--the Euro sign.  However, if you paste that sequence into a file, it will be five characters long: a `\`, and  a `2`, and a `0`, and an `A`, and a `C`.

**Response to comment:**

There is an invisible [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) at the start of the json, which you can see by executing:

```
p resp
```

...which produces the output:

```
\xEF\xBB\xBF[{\"id\":\"2388\" .....
```

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence
>   0xEF,0xBB,0xBF
>
> Byte order has no meaning in UTF-8,[4] so its only use in UTF-8 is to
>   signal at the start that the text stream is encoded in UTF-8.

You can skip the first 3 bytes/characters like this:

```
resp[3..-1]
```

Comment: Oh. I see.. So If I need to read it from file and parse it, then how could I do it.

Comment: ok.. But in other scenario of my code I need to parse it without writing it to a file. So basically my code will try to get the body of the given json url using ruby script and store it in a variable.After that it would try to parse the response.

Comment: Write the string to a file.  For instance, if you write the string `"hello \"world\"\n"` to a file, then open up the file with a text editor, you will see `hello "world"`.  If you read the file with a ruby program, you will get the string: `"hello \"world\"\n"`

Comment: *So basically my code will try to get the body of the given json url using ruby script and store it in a variable.After that it would try to parse the response.*  Parse away.  If the String returned by your http request is valid json, ruby will parse it for you.

Comment: The string returned by http request is a valid json. I tried in jsonlint and it shows valid. But still it throws parser error which is what wondering me.

Comment: I am trying to get the json response from the below url. http://mytf1vod.tf1.fr/films.html?offset=1&count=1

Comment: @rubyist, See my response at bottom of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72555/discussion-between-rubyist-and-7stud).

Answer (score 2):

I had this error with reading in JSON files and it turned out that the issue was that JSON.parse somehow did not like UTF-8-encoded files. When I first encoded the files to ASCII (= ISO 8859-1) everything went fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It works.

```
require 'json'
my_obj = JSON.parse("your json string", :symbolize_names => true)
```

Comment: Then there's something else missing. Can you show your code? Also, what version of ruby are you using?